# change UIbutton color inside UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uibutton

I have a simple problem ... but its turning into a very difficult problem .. i have a button inside uitableviewcell and want to change its color through code .... i could aceive it by changing its background image. But its kinna hazy ... its not the solid color ... and when i use [cell.button setBackgroundColor:[UIcolor redColor]] ... the button color does not change ...

any help appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how are you doing this, but if it is possible, why don't you keep reference to this button.

You can initialize it, insert it on your table and all the time that you need to change something, you use the variable that you have initialized.

```
// On your .h
UIButton *myButton;

// On your .m
// Initialize it.


// when displaying cells
cell.button = myButton;


// when you need to change the color use your myButton reference
myButton.backgroundColor = ......
```

Cheers,
VFN

Comment: hey thanks ... 

somebody pointed out that .. UIButton is inherited from UIView ... so the background property belogs to UIView and will not change the color ...

when i am doing cell.button .. then button is UIButton IBOutlet to the real button on the xib 

 Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi. So, the button will inherit the UIView BG because you are clearing the background color. If you want to change the color for something different from the UIView BG, you will need to set some color.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a background image (correct me if I got it wrong) then there is no chance to change the background color (or, at least, see this change) without changing the background image...

If you don't have a BG image then it should work...

Where do you change the color?

Inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` or do you have a reference to the button?

UPDATE:

Haven't noticed the `[cell.button`.

What is `cell`?

Comment: hey thanks ... cell's the UITableViewCell instance that i create and return in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and button is IBOutlet for the roundbutton on the xib

If i use the image .. i do get green and red button ... but its not in its true color ... its very very hazy .... and somebody pointed out that .. UIButton is inherited from UIView ... so the background property belogs to UIView and will not change the color ... 

Any other ideas?

Comment: Now I think that I understand your problem. Correct me if I'm wrong. You have a round-rect button and you want to change its background color so the button will still have transparent rounded corners. If this is the case then I would advise you to switch images. I don't think that there is a real app in the air that uses round-rect button and not a custom one with image...

Answer (score 0):

Actually changing the background color would change the corners of the button slightly but you may not notice it as rounded rect button just blocks its background as long as it is not transparent.

I believe what you want to do is to change the tint color.

try

```
 [cell.button setTintColor:[UIcolor redColor]];
```

I guess it should work.